# Watch trigger in multiple zookeeper server

Tags: hadoop, apache-zookeeper

I have 3 zookeeper servers in a cluster.
My Client has connected to server1 and created a Watch for Update in node /MYNODE
If the server1 goes off One of the other server will be Master . So Will my watch trigger will still be functional ?

Comment: Why don't you look in the user guide?

Comment: User guide says it will ....

Comment: so, you are saying it's not working in you case?

Comment: [SOLVED]It was not working in my case due to some file system ACL permission .Now It is working ..thanks

Comment: Glad that you figured it out :)